# Is this explicit heap or stack dynamic?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Given the following code snippet in C:

```
int* x;
x = (int *) malloc(40);
```

We know that this is an explicit heap dynamic allocation.

If I change the code to this though:

```
int* x = (int *) malloc(40);
```

is it still an explicit heap dynamic? My friend thinks it's a stack dynamic, but I think its an explicit heap dynamic because we're allocating memory from the heap.

Explicit heap dynamic is defined as variables that are allocated and deallocated by explicit run-time instructions written by the programmer. Wouldn't that imply that any malloc/calloc call would be explicit heap?

---

Edit: I spoke to my professor and she clarified some stuff for me.

When we declare something like

```
char * str = (char *) malloc(15);
```

We say that str is of data type char pointer, and has a stack dynamic storage binding. However, when we are referring to the object referenced by str, we say that it is explicit heap dynamic.

Comment: Why are you casting the return of malloc?

Comment: There is nothing called heap which the standard boasts of.

Comment: Heap dynamic and stack dynamic? I'm confused.

Comment: "Stack dynamic" and "heap dynamic" are not standard terminology, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You should presumably be assigning to `int *x` rather than `int x` — storing a pointer in an integer is not a good idea.

Comment: `x` is allocated in automatic storage – usually the stack.  The data that `x` would point at if it were a pointer is allocated dynamically — off the heap.  The two sets of code are equivalent in general terms; there is no difference in the memory allocation schemes.

Comment: @Quentin.: It's implemenattion defined.

Comment: Think about it; how could `malloc` do something different depending on whether it is called as an initialiser or in an assignment?  How would you write a function with that capability?  You can't.  The second ensures that at no point is `x` uninitialised, so generally safer.  Dynamic allocation on the stack is achieved with `alloca()` or a VLA.

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you are going to store the results of `malloc` in a variable, then declare it properly as a pointer, not an int. 
The problem with storing the malloc results in an int, is that you could possibly truncate the pointer and blow up when you dereference it later. For instance if you ran that expression on a 64 bit system, the malloc would come back with a 8 byte pointer. But since you are assigning it to a 4 byte int, it gets truncated. Not good.

Your code should be like this:

```
int* x = (int*)malloc(bla);
```

Anyways, the int pointer `x` itself is stored on the stack. But don't get the two confused. X itself is a pointer on the stack, but it points to memory allocated on the heap.

Note:

32 bit applications (usually) have 4 byte pointers.

64 bit applications (usually) have 8 byte pointers.

Comment: Hmmm.  "64 bit applications have 8 byte pointers." is not quite a truism. 
 N-bit apps usually refers to the native integer size of the target processor.  This often affects the selection of the `int` and `long` size.  The pointer size is secondary and may not match the N-bit app size or `int`/`long` size.  Further: function pointer size may differ from object pointer size.  Many possibilities.

Comment: Ok, I clarified it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `malloc` allocates requested memory on the heap. Heap memory is used for dynamic data structures that grow and shrink.

Answer (score 1):

From standard [6.3.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6)

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, *the result is implementation-defined*. ***If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined***. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

This claims why the type of the pointer should be `int*`. Also the casting is not needed - `void*` to `int*` conversion will be implicitly done over here.

Also why do you think declaring a variable with initializer or without it would affect the storage duration of the memory allocated by `*alloc` and it's friend functions. It is not.

Interesting thing `x` has automatic storage duration (usually this is realized using stack) but the memory it contains (yes type of `x` would be `int*`) - it will be of allocated storage duration. The thing is heap/stack are not something specified or mentioned by C standard. Most implementations usually realize allocated storage duration using heap.

Comment: I'm actually asking this question (if declaring a variable with an initializer would affect storage duration) because I was looking through the slide deck from class and there was an example [ int *dist = malloc(sizeof(int)*n); ]. According to the slides, this is stack dynamic, and the stack dynamic variable is the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bad example for malloc. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Katrina.: It will be heap allocated provided in your case it is heap on which allocation storage durtion is implemented

Comment: I think my confusion is in that I thought that since the memory was allocated as a heap, that must mean that the pointer is "heap-dynamic". But as pointed out by @C Johnson, the int pointer is stored on the stack, and it points to a memory allocated by a heap.

Comment: @Katrina.: That's what I said. The variable itself is of automatic storage duration but the memory address which it contains if allocated in heap -it's the heap memorie's address.

Comment: @Katrina.: `x` is different from what you allocate..you are using `x` to acess it but `x` is not dynamically allocated. Make it clear.